# Using $set() to add a User object to /users in Firebase

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I'm currently trying to add new users to Firebase via the AngularFire `$set()` method. I'm creating new users via the `$createUser` method from AngularFire. My code looks like this:

```
$scope.createUser = function() {
      $scope.auth.$createUser('dolly@gmail.com', 'password').then(function(user, err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
        } else {
          sync.$set('users', user);
        }
      });
}
```

This is a creating new user and placing the new user object inside of users:{..}, however, it is also adding an additional user child object thats just duplicate data -- this is what the code is adding to Firebase:

```
{
"users": {
    "email": "dolly@gmail.com",
    "id": "11",
    "isTemporaryPassword": false,
    "md5_hash": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "provider": "password",
    "sessionKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0MDc5NDQ2NDYsInYiOjAsImQiOnsicHJvdmlkZXIiOiJwYXNzd29yZCIsImlkIjoiMTEiLCJ1aWQiOiJzaW1wbGVsb2dpbjoxMSIsImVtYWlsIjoiZG9sbHlAZ21haWwuY29tIiwibWQ1X2hhc2giOiIzsdrggfeedsaadrfcDc0ZDRhMTU5NTk2NzI1NzFmMDk2ZTZlNyIsImlzVGVtcG9yYXJ5UGFzc3dvcmQiOmZhbHNlLCJzZXNzaW9uS2V5IjoiM2MwMDNjODkxMDEzOWE5MjhlZTZjNWI1NjU5ZTRiZjMifSwiaWF0IjoxNDA3ODU4MjQ2fQ.p7-9GDtaNpBn1ICTLIUSwlPytaUGi-jyBgcO-LKHUys",
    "uid": "simplelogin:11",
    "user": {
    "email": "dolly@gmail.com",
    "id": "11",
    "isTemporaryPassword": false,
    "md5_hash": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "provider": "dfrggrssxxxxxxx",
    "sessionKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "uid": "simplelogin:11"
    }
}
```

I ideally want my users object to look like the example in firebase, except with each user key to be whatever is inside `user.uid`

```
users: {
    user1: {
      name: "Alice"
    },
    user2: {
      name: "Bob"
    }
}
```

Where each new user will be added to the `users: {...}` key without the duplicate user child tacked on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create a reference to `users/` and then call `$set` on that path, then whatever data you include will replace anything at that path. This is [AngularFire 101](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-basics). You should begin by reading at least that section if not the entire guide.

Choose the path you want to set data at when creating your sync object.

```
var ref = new Firebase('.../users/'+user.uid);
var sync = $firebase(ref);
sync.$set({ email: user.email, provider: user.provider });
```

Or, better yet, just set it on the reference since you aren't utilizing this for client-side bindings.

```
var ref = new Firebase('.../users/'+user.uid);
ref.set({ email: user.email, provider: user.provider });
```

Creating profiles is explained in the [Firebase docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing) and covered in the AngularFire-Seed repo's [createProfile service](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed/blob/master/app/js/simpleLogin.js), nearly verbatim to your example.

Comment: Try reading [the guide](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire) for a version of this answer less than 2 years old.